# DynamicJasper - UTF-8 character not showed

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm using DynamicJasper to generate Pdf files.

In the application.properties file I have a property with this value:

```
reports.info = To get information call  5555-1234
```

For that, I'm using a AutoText, to put that in the footer.

```
AutoText info = new AutoText(messageSupportHelper.getMessage("reports.info1"),
                AutoText.POSITION_FOOTER, HorizontalBandAlignment.CENTER);
        info.setWidth(700);
        info.setStyle(createTitleHeaderStyle());
```

And the method of the style is:

```
private Style createTitleHeaderStyle() {

        Style style = Style.createBlankStyle("ASDASDASDASD");
        style.setFont(new Font(7, DEJA_VU_SANS, true, false, false));
        style.getFont().setPdfFontEncoding(Font.PDF_ENCODING_Identity_H_Unicode_with_horizontal_writing);
        style.getFont().setPdfFontEmbedded(true);
        style.setTextColor(new Color(60, 153, 124));
        style.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        style.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        return style;
    }
```

But phone icon is not showed in the pdf file.
I tried also these ways:

```
reports.info = To get information call  5555-1234
reports.info = To get information call &#128222; 5555-1234
reports.info = To get information call \uD83D\uDCDE 5555-1234
```

But I have the same result.

Do you know what is happening?